# jquery validate plugin

Tags: jquery, validation

I am trying to validate a form using the jquery validate plugin.  In my form, there is an 'ip' field and a 'mac' field for ip and mac address resp.  Here is the code:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('IP4Checker', function(value) {
    var ip = "^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[0-9]{2}"+
             "|[0-9])(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[0-9]{2}|[0-9])){3}$";
    return value.match(ip);
}, ' Invalid IP Address');


jQuery.validator.addMethod('MACChecker', function(value) {
    var mac = "^([0-9a-fA-F]{2}:){5}[0-9a-fA-F]{2}$";
    return value.match(mac);
}, ' Invalid MAC Address');

// Validate form
jQuery('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
        mac: {
            MACChecker : true
        },
        ip: {
            IP4Checker: true
        }
    }
});
```

Now, when the user clicks "Ok" button inside a jquery dialog, i want to validate this form.  However it keeps coming back as false, even when there is valid input.

```
// dialog box
jQuery('#mydialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: {
        Cancel: function() {
            jQuery(this).dialog('close');
        },
        Ok: function() {
            jQuery('#myform').validate();

            var valid = jQuery('#myform').valid();

            alert("valid = "+valid);

            if(!valid){
                    return false;
            }
...
```

It just doesn't want to evaluate to true.  I tried it without the `jQuery('#myform').validate();` above, same result.  What's going on?

Comment: Oh it could be because one is valid and one isn't.  How do I make it so if one is blank but the other is filled out and valid, then it all valid?

Comment: 1. allow in your IP and MAC validation functions for empty input, 2. add to each of the elements another rule which checks that if current value is empty, that the other textbox is not. something like: `jQuery.validator.addMethod('IPEmptyAndMacNot', function(value) {
    return value != '' || $("#txtMac").val() != '';
}, 'Must have one field filled');
`

Comment: nevermind, should be simple case of checking if value is empty in the addmethods()'s